# Reading a file from different machines in python

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing

I'm running an application using several different machines via an scheduler server from which I request resources. 
I was having some problems creating temporary files from different processes, so I have divided my temps into different directories. (each process has it's own directory now).
However all of the processes are trying to read from the same file.

Could that cause race conditions? could I somehow lock the file?

```
#  This code is called in parallel from different machines.
def main(argv=None):

settings = process_command_line(argv)
#  genes_file is a shared resource.
with open(settings.genes_file) as genes_file:
    features, feat_list = count_fragments.read_gtf( 
    genes_file, settings.feature, settings.gene_iden)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you just reading from the file?

Comment: Yes, Only reading.

Comment: If the file is not changing and you are only reading, then there is no possibility for a race condition.